# Moment Timezone JS to insert Central Date/Time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I discovered Moment JS but I am struggling on how to achieve what I want.  All I want is to return the current date and time in Central (Chicago time) in this format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

This is how I'm capturing the timestamp now but it uses the system time and not Chicago time.

```
            function getTimeStamp() {
               var now = new Date();
               return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                             + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                             .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
        }
        function setTime() {
            document.getElementById('InsertRecordDate_Received').value = getTimeStamp();
        }
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is not only use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/), but you need to use [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).  Using this you can do `moment().tz('America/Chicago').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss')` and it should do exactly what you need.

Check out this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqvAg6URqzeJnVujKq8x) for an example using your code.

Comment: @user2653658 That looks as tho it should work.  I would advise that you modify the cases of the format though.  I initially copied and pasted what your format was and  it is slightly wrong. Instead use this `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  I implemented it and it doesn't seem to be performing as expected.  https://jsfiddle.net/unuz0xh5/4/

Does it matter that I'm trying to pass the value into a form field?  Does it need to be converted to a different data type?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter as long as the you are putting in a type of form field that can accept a string.  I am a bit unsure as to what your implementation is.  You are using a NodeJS implementation in the `getTimeStamp` function, but then you are loading the scripts in the html.  As long as you have moment and moment timezone loaded it should work.

Comment: I think this is exposing the level or rust I have on my dev skills but I am not using Node.js on this project.  I downloaded the documents and have them in my folder with my other javascripts documents.  Do I have to call these up differently in my `getTimeStamp` function?

Comment: @user2653658 check out the plunker that I added in my answer.  It works and does what you want.

Comment: That did it!! 

`<script data-require="moment.js@*" data-semver="2.14.1" src="https://npmcdn.com/moment@2.14.1"></script>
      <script data-require="moment-timezone-with-data@*" data-semver="0.4.0" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>`

  Thanks so much for all your help!!!

Comment: @user2653658 Its no problem. I have had my struggles with momentjs too lol.

Answer (score 0):

Moment has a `.format()` method. Simply call `moment()` to get the current date and then chain the `.format()` method with your format string. This, in turn, will return a string which you can set as your value.

```
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS');
```

You may need to adjust your format since you have `MM` for month and minutes.